# insertar automáticamente un caracter mientras escribo en un input

Tags: jquery, html

Necesito insertar el caracter ":" mientras estoy escribiendo números en un input tipo texto, el ":" debe insertarse automáticamente cuando haya escrito dos números, algo como esto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora con el snipet:

```js
$(document).ready(Principal);
    function Principal(){
        var flag1 = true;
        $(document).on('keydown','[id=inputime1]',function(e){
            if($(this).val().length == 2 && flag1) {
                $(this).val($(this).val()+":");
                flag1 = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="inputime1" type="text">
</body>
```

Pero el resultado que obtengo es que los ":" no se ingresan cuando ponga el segundo caracter, sino el tercero.

Alguna idea de por qué ocurre esto y cómo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Pero el resultado que obtengo es que los ":" no se ingresan cuando ponga el segundo caracter, sino el tercero. Alguna idea de por qué ocurre esto

Eso ocurre porque estás realizando la acción cuando se pulsa la tecla (`keydown`), entonces no se realizará la comprobación al terminar de escribir el segundo carácter, sino al comenzar a escribir el tercer carácter.

> y cómo solucionarlo?

Una solución rápida: en lugar de añadir las comprobaciones en el `keydown`, hazlo en el `keyup`, así se realizarán cuando se suelte la tecla (al final del segundo carácter).

El código sería así:

```js
$(document).ready(Principal);
    function Principal(){
        var flag1 = true;
        $(document).on('keyup','[id=inputime1]',function(e){
            if($(this).val().length == 2 && flag1) {
                $(this).val($(this).val()+":");
                flag1 = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="inputime1" type="text">
</body>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, como siempre :D

Answer (score 0):

```
function Principal(){
    var flag1 = true;
    $(document).on('keyup','[id=inputime1]',function(e){
        if($(this).val().length == 2 && flag1) {
            $(this).val($(this).val()+"-");
            flag1 = true;
        }
        else if($(this).val().length == 7 && flag1) {
            $(this).val($(this).val()+":");
            flag1 = false;
        }
    });
  }
```

solo repites el código y devuelve verdadero en el primero...

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee **[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Es recomendable que agregues una explicación de este código.